# как проверить была ли нажата кнопка?

Tags: android, android-studio, button, android-button

нужно проверить было ли нажатие на кнопку, то есть сейчас в программе я могу при достижении определенного значения переменной сделать кнопку 1 недоступной, но у меня есть еще одна кнопка 2 при нажатии на которую мне нужно сделать кнопку 1 опять доступной.

```
if (simpleValue <= 20 && simpleValue > 0) {
simpleValue = simpleValue - 2;
if(simpleValue == 0)
{
findViewById(R.id.up).setEnabled(false);
}
}
```

это фрагмент кода, где я делаю кнопку недоступной, а мне нужно еще добавить что бы при нажатии на кнопку 2 я опять давай возможность пользоваться кнопкой 1 но опять таки при достижении значения 0 переменной у меня опять кнопка 1 делалась недоступной. Думал сделать MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN но я не знаю как привязать эту фигню к определенной кнопке. Возможно я не сильно понятно объяснил вопрос, если что спрашивайте буду что то добавлять или дообъяснять.

Comment: Поставьте слушатель на OnClick и проверяйте в нем значение переменной, если значение норм, тогда активируйте ту кнопку которую вам нужно.

Comment: а на слушатель OnTouch пойдет?

Comment: Лучше на клик, а то будет на всякую мелочь код выполнять.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В слушателе второй кнопки прежде чем сделать 1 кнопку активной, проверьте активна ли она

```
if(!button.isEnabled()) button.setEnabled(true);//если не активна, активировать
```

Comment: setEnabled - не делает кнопку невидимой, а просто ее вырубает

Comment: да да, думаю одно пишу другое, спасибо, поправлю

Comment: вроде добавил эту строку и нормально заработало так как нужно